# Executing jar file from Terminal in kbuntu

Tags: java, linux, jar

I have created a .jar file from source .java file,And i'm trying to execute it from the Terminal but shows the following error:
**Failed to load Main-Class manifest attribute from
myclass.jar**

Please some one help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Folks I got the solution from :http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html

Comment: That's the link I posted you in my answer. If you are happy with it, don't forget to mark one answer as "solved"...

Answer (score 0):

Just try -

`jar cmf Manifest.txt MyClass.jar Myclass.class`

My manifest.txt file content:

`Main-Class: MyClass`